# SetAttribute doesn't work in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 and the `attr()` method, It's working fine on all browsers except IE7.

In the console, It highlights the setAttribute function in jQuery JS and says: **Not Implemented**

I think IE7 doesn't support that, so i tried to work around it:

```
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAttribute')){
  $(e).attr(key, value);
}else{
  e[key] = value;
}
```

It's still telling me:

**Object doesn't support this action**

What's the solution for this?

Comment: Well, the `setAttribute` method is certainly not defined on the `Object.prototype` object... It's defined on [the *Element* interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-element) of the DOM standard.

Comment: The setAttribute function in jQuery JS? But jQuery doesn't have a setAttribute function... Just `$(e).attr(key, value);` should work in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery handles all odd cases well, there's usually no need to work around anything. Also note what Šime Vidas said, `setAttribute` isn't defined on `Object.prototype` and even if it would be, in IE8 and lower HTML elements don't inherit from `Object` so the feature detection wouldn't probably work as expected.

What's the value of `key` variable? Consider using `prop()` if more appropriate, or `addClass()` if you work with classes.

Comment: The value of key is src, or action, or href.

Answer (score 1):

duri is exactly right. Even if `setAttribute` doesn't work on IE7, jQuery's `.attr()` does. The whole point behind jQuery is to smooth over these differences between browsers, and give you a framework where common actions will 'just work'.

Remove the conditional from your code, and just leave this:

```
$(e).attr(key, value);
```

Let jQuery handle the rest for you; that's what it's for.

If that still doesn't work, update your question with the values of e, key, and value, and people might be able to help further.